# PyMinuit vs IMinuit

Tags: python, minimization, pyminuit, iminuit

I was looking for a minuit equivalent on Python 2.7 and I found this two variants:
[PyMinuit](https://code.google.com/p/pyminuit/) and
[iMinuit](https://github.com/iminuit/iminuit).

My question is: what's the difference between them?

Both uses Seal 1.7.9 Minuit and in a few 2D Gaussian fit tests that I had both brought the same answers. So, beside the installation method (iMinuit being easier), why should I choose one over the other?

Thanks for your help! xD

P.S. I tryied to tag iminuit as well but I can't create a new tag... =/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Disclaimer: I wrote iminuit. Let me give you a bit of history.

I was a proud user of PyMinuit. I loved it and the syntax he came up with is just brilliant. However, I eventually found that I couldn't really do build a cost function programatically(and efficiently). For example, if you want to make a generic chi^2 functor which takes the data and the pdf of n parameter as the arguments and spit out a chi^2 function of n-1 parameter, it is (almost)impossible to do in PyMinuit.

So, I try to modify PyMinuit to add that exact function and to modify some print out. I found that PyMinuit code is in C which is a pain to modify. So, I rewrite it using cython.

Couple addition you will find in iminuit:

1. [Better integration](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/iminuit/iminuit/master/tutorial/tutorial.ipynb) with IPython notebook. It prints the result in a nice table and can graph you for free a couple things.
2. [Function signature extraction](http://iminuit.github.io/iminuit/api.html#function-sig-label) is much more forgiving than PyMinuit
3. [Long parameter name](https://github.com/iminuit/iminuit/issues/44). Not really PyMinuit Bug but there is a bug in Minuit 1.7.x that the name length was hardcoded.
4. [One side limit](https://github.com/iminuit/iminuit/issues/96) I'm not sure but I think PyMinuit doesn't do this
5. Progress printout is a bit different but it's a matter of taste. The one I have is inspired by ROOT which IMO make more sense.
6. [probfit](https://github.com/iminuit/probfit) integration. Remember I mention function that takes data and pdf and spit out chi^2 function for minimization? See [tutorial](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/iminuit/probfit/master/tutorial/tutorial.ipynb).

Comment: The PyMinuit author now also recommends iminuit: https://github.com/jpivarski/pyminuit#pyminuit---minuit-numerical-function-minimization-in-python

Comment: Yes: install iminuit. (I'm the author of PyMinuit.) I'm using iminuit in tutorials for new students.